# MATH reverting rotated coordinates

Tags: javascript, math, fabricjs

The situation:

The canvas contains an image, which can be rotated, scaled and translated (moved).
The image is an SVG with many paths inside, thus the original coordinates must be retrieved to check which path is encapsulating the mouse.

The SVG is rendered on a canvas.

```
      //calculates the distance between two points
      var distance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(x1 - x2), 2),
            Math.pow(Math.abs(y1 - y2), 2));
      };

      //defines the center of the image
      //this is also the rotational point
      var center = {
        x : target.getWidth() / 2,
        y : target.getHeight() / 2
      };

      //defines the click location
      var click = {
        x : event.layerX / target.getScaleX() - target.getLeft(),
        y : event.layerY / target.getScaleY() - target.getTop()
      };
```

Above code makes sure the `x` and `y` are the correct values used within the paths, provided there is no rotation.

So basically: provided the user has rotated the image 45 degrees and clicks on the image: the click coordinates need to be rotated back 45 degrees to get the needed coordinates. But it's been a few years since I've done maths like that...

The origin (rotational point) of the image is its center.

Comment: Do you know the angle and the centre of rotation?

Comment: Yes, I have access to both.

Comment: Are you sure you can't cheat and use the browser's mouse events?

Comment: How do you mean, Eric?

Comment: `<path onmouseover="selection=this">`

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508803/how-to-get-transformed-rotated-svg-path-points

Comment: Nevermind, just spotted you have a canvas with a _rendered_ svg

Comment: Ah, right, sadly that's not a viable solution as the default SVGs that come with the software could easily contain this... but users are also able to upload SVGs and I don't think I could create this attribute at runtime with fabricjs, or can I? (Current way to load a test image: https://gist.github.com/StephanBijzitter/9a26e737a469d2fb5dec)

Comment: Yeah, should've mentioned that, my bad.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question here - you shouldn't be asking "how do I do the math", but "how can I get fabricjs to do the math for me?"

Comment: Not really, as I'd be good with either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `toLocalPoint`, which does most of the work for you : http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#toLocalPoint

As you can [see in the source of the function](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line11630), it does not take into account scaling, but it does the rotation and translation of the object.

```
var p = canvas.getPointer(event);
var loc = target.toLocalPoint(new fabric.Point(p.x,p.y), "left", "top");

var pos_in_target = {
    x : loc.x / target.getScaleX(),
    y : loc.y / target.getScaleY()
};
```

Comment: With your first answer I felt blessed because you went into so much detail and when I got back from my break I saw the edit (current version as of typing) and I was like what nooo where did it go! I do understand now (because of your earlier revision) how it all works, and with an implementation as simple as this... you're the best man, thanks a lot

Comment: Haha yeah, I went into some detail, that you can access here : http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27757399/7, but though I get the opposite matrix just fine, I get into trouble getting the matrix from fabricjs. Using  `getTransformMatrix()` always returns `null`, and `fabric.parseTransformAttribute(target.getSvgTransform())` fails by forgetting a degree to radians conversion, so I had to build the matrix manually. Then going through the code, I found lots of useful functions that are less obvious in the doc... hence the shorter answer. But see a comparison here : http://jsfiddle.net/1fy8s309/4